# Jujucharms API error 401 unauthorized

Tags: juju, maas

I'm getting several API errors from jujucharms:

```
GET https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/~kubernetes/trusty/kubernetes-11/icon.svg 401 (Unauthorized)
```

When entering the URL directly I get the following:

> { Message: "access denied for user "ejperezf"", Code: "unauthorized" }

This is a fresh Juju install using Maas. I can't add bundles.

I am also getting this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/~admin/default/meta/any?include=bundle-metadata&include=bundle-machine-count&include=charm-config&include=charm-metadata&include=charm-metrics&include=common-info&include=extra-info&include=id-revision&include=manifest&include=owner&include=published&include=resources&include=revision-info&include=stats&include=supported-series&include=tags' from origin 'https://10.110.25.37:17070' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And when trying to add a bundle:

```
cannot fetch the entity no entity data returned, can you access the charmstore?

GET https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/bundle/openstack-base-61/meta/any?include=bundle-metadata&include=bundle-machine-count&include=charm-config&include=charm-metadata&include=charm-metrics&include=common-info&include=extra-info&include=id-revision&include=manifest&include=owner&include=published&include=resources&include=revision-info&include=stats&include=supported-series&include=tags net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Is this still affecting you? There was a outage with the charm store API, but I believe it's been resolved.

Comment: @TimMcNamara It was an issue with the API calls that was solved in the new GUI version (v2.15.0)

Comment: Really glad to hear that this has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the API calls in GUI version 2.14.0. It has been fixed in v2.15.0. Upgrade the GUI using `juju upgrade-gui`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just outdated links.You'd need to get into a newer supported charm to get a valid icon for it.

https://github.com/juju/juju-gui/issues/2948

Comment: I added more info on the errors I'm getting.